# Javascript: Accessing properties of keys of a Hashtable

Tags: javascript

I wanted to use a hashtable as set of some objects for a graphic libray, so that I can quickly remove these objects by saying something like `set.remove(v2)`.

But it appears I cannot use these objects while I try to iterate the set, since the keys don't have the right properties, even though a `==` shows that they are the same objects!

What can I do to iterate the set and use the properties or functions which are part of the keys?

Test case shown below, with rather unexpected results (for me)!

```
v1={'a':2,'b':3};
set={};
set[v1]=true;

// Access the object within set
var v2; for(var k in set) v2=k;

// At this moment, v2 and v1 should be the same object, but...

console.log(v2==v1);    // returns true
console.log(JSON.stringify(v1)); // returns {"a":2,"b":3}
console.log(JSON.stringify(v2)); // returns "[object Object]"   !!!
console.log(v1.a);  // returns 2
console.log(v2.a);  // causes error 'reference to undefined property v2.a' !!!
```

Comment: First of all, always use `===` over `==` to avoid type casting giving you a false positive. If you run `console.log(v2===v1)` you will find they are not in fact the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set an object as the key of another object, which isn't possible in current ECMAScript implementations.  When you call `set[v1]=true;`, internally the engine converts `v1` to a string, the result being `"[object Object]"` with no identifiable properties.

ECMAScript 6 allows you to map objects to other values using [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), but the API is still in the early stages and currently only available in Chrome—with a command line switch—and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other way I can maintain a list of objects with O(1) search or deletion?

Comment: Try something like `set["obj1"] = v1;`

Comment: @KalEl: not with objects for keys, unless you can live with ES5 implementations only (most newer browsers).  For that, there's a [WeakMap shim](https://gist.github.com/1638059) that is O(1) for search and deletion.